# How to decode static JSON file with special chars

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1

My static JSON file has content like:

```
  {
     "language": "de",
     "translations": {
        "language": "Deutsch",
        "checkingPrivileges": "Rechte werden überprüft..."
     }
  }
```

I am requesting the static file successfully:

```
// strUrl = '/src/plugins/usermanagement/language/de.json';
Ext.Ajax.request( {
        url: strUrl,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
        success: oCallbacks.success,
        failure: oCallbacks.failure,
        scope: this
     } );
```

And decoding the content:

```
var oJson = Ext.JSON.decode( oResponse.responseText );
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "language": "de",
  "translations": {
     "language": "Deutsch",
     "checkingPrivileges": "Rechte werden �berpr�ft..."
  }
```

}

My page is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

I read a couple of posts. So how do I get the umlauts displayed?

Comment: Yes thanks. Indeed the file itself was saved as `ISO 8859-15`. I have saved it now as `UTF-8` and it works. What is the best to convert a file `ISO 8859-15` to `UTF-8` on Linux? Richie post an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your static file UTF-8? It looks as though it's actually latin - if so, you should convert it to UTF-8.  Since you're on Linux, the `iconv` command is your friend.  :-)